# Loop over a large list of elements and calculate mean in R

Tags: r, time, split, average

The procedure involved to get the structure I needed to essentially do what I want is quite long, so please bear with me.

I've created a large list of daily elements which are split into separate weeks:

```
jobs <- sample(1:100, size = 4018, replace = TRUE)
unemployed <- sample(1:100, size = 4018, replace = TRUE)
insurance <- sample(1:100, size = 4018, replace = TRUE)
daily_seq <- seq(as.Date("2004-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), by = "days")
daily_df <- data.frame(daily_seq, jobs, unemployed, insurance)
library(xts)
daily_xts <- xts(daily_df[-1], order.by = as.Date(daily_seq))
# split daily series into list of daily series split by calendar months:
split_list1 <- split(daily_xts, f = "months", drop = FALSE, k = 1)
# split further into large list of weekly elements with daily data define by week number 1:4:
splitlist1 = NULL
for (i in 1:length(split_list1)) {
intervals <- cut(.indexmday(split_list1[[1]]), c(0, 7, 14, 21, 31), 1:4)
splitlist1[[i]] <- split(split_list1[[i]], intervals)
splitlist1
}
```

Where `splitlist1` is the large list of balanced calendar week elements.

What I'm essentially trying to do is loop over each "week" and calculate a weekly average of the daily series.

I created a sequence of dates to correspond to the weeks I want for the desired output matrix object:

```
# date sequence corresponding to weekly averaged dates needed. "v2" is the sequence:
library(lubridate)
v1 <- seq(as.Date("2004-01-01"), as.Date("201-12-31"), by = "week")
lst <- split(v1, list(month(v1), year(v1)), drop=TRUE) # split vector into months and years
days <- substr(v1[1:4],9,10) # substring extracts first 4 observations from a month as the basis of the sequence
v2 <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(y) {
sprintf('%s%s', substr(y[1:4], 1,8), days)}), use.names=FALSE)

# create matrix for desired output:
week_matrix = matrix(NA, nrow = length(v2), ncol = ncol(split_list1[[1]]), dimnames = dimnames(split_list1[[1]][1]))
```

I then went ahead to calculate the corresponding averages with these lines of code:

```
# loop through each weekly element "j" of daily data and calculate weekly average:
for (i in 1:length(splitlist1)) {
for (j in 1:4) {
for (n in 1:ncol(splitlist1[[1]]$`1`)){
 week_matrix[i,n] <- weighted.mean(splitlist1[[i]]$'j'[,n])
 week_matrix
 }}}
```

However, it returns an error related to the line of code `Error in 1:ncol(splitlist1[[1]]$j) : argument of length 0` even though running this line for a specific week `j` returns an integer.
Also, if I remove this line of code, it presents an empty matrix with no calculations in it.

I have tried every possible variation of my lines of code that I could think of, however I haven't been able to produce the output I want. My desired output is to be a matrix/xts type object with the weekly averages along the rows corresponding to the `v2` date sequence, and columns corresponding to `jobs; unemployed; and insurance`

Can you guys please assist me with this?! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your original time series and weekly time series are different lengths. This may be causing your problem. However, the answers below use a lot less code so give them a try!

Comment: @MikeRSpencer - Sorry, my bad. Fixed, but same issue. Will give it a go.

Comment: When you ask a question, try and only ask one thing. At the moment this is a question titled about lists and means, but with a lot of time series generation problems. These should be separate questions, rather than 'here's my code - fix it'.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a job for tapply, by, or aggregate like tools in dplyr. The key is developing the index you want to iterate over. Here's an example using tapply.

Create your dummy data:

```
jobs <- sample(1:100, size = 4018, replace = TRUE)
unemployed <- sample(1:100, size = 4018, replace = TRUE)
insurance <- sample(1:100, size = 4018, replace = TRUE)
daily_seq <- seq(as.Date("2004-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), by = "days")
daily_df <- data.frame(daily_seq, jobs, unemployed, insurance)
```

Add an index to uniquely identify each week:

```
daily_df$week = rep(seq(as.Date("2004-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"),
    by = "week"), each=7)
daily_df$YR.week = paste(strftime(daily_df$daily_seq, "%Y"), daily_df_week)
```

Repeat your mean for each set grouped by year and week:

```
tapply(daily_df$jobs, daily_df$YR.week, mean)
```

Comment: I've tried it with the `"%U"` format before but it assumes that each week and month starts on a Sunday which isn't the case here - So I've had to manually set up a sequence of dates, if you know what I mean

Comment: OK, the method still stands: create a column with yr and week number and use it as the index for your iteration. I'll amend my answer to reflect - good luck!

Comment: Here's the deal. I've had to define each week in a way whereby every fourth week of a particular month varies depending on the number of days in each month (i.e. 28, 29, 30, and 31 inclusive of leap years).

Comment: So essentially, `each=7` in the code isn't really the case. What do you suppose I should do there?

Comment: each=7 relates repeating the week number for 7 days, not the whole month. So the method I've written gives you the average for each week of each year, the months are irrelevant.

Comment: Yep. `tapply` didn't calculate means - just spat out the same daily values. I do get the whole index thing though...I'll figure it out as best I can. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Same philosophy as @MikeRSpencer described.
I'm using lubridate and dplyr packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

jobs <- sample(1:100, size = 4018, replace = TRUE)
unemployed <- sample(1:100, size = 4018, replace = TRUE)
insurance <- sample(1:100, size = 4018, replace = TRUE)
daily_seq <- seq(as.Date("2004-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), by = "days")
daily_df <- data.frame(daily_seq, jobs, unemployed, insurance)


daily_df %>%
  mutate(WeekOfYear = week(daily_seq)) %>% # obtain week of year
  group_by(WeekOfYear) %>% # group by that 
  select(-daily_seq) %>% # remove variables you don't need to average on
  summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Note that as the variable "week of year" will be repeated if you include many years in your dataset, you can use a combination of "week of year" and "year" for your grouping.

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm essentially trying to do is loop over each "week" and calculate a >weekly average of the daily series.

If I understand you correctly you would like to start each beginning of a month with "monthweek" number 1.
Let's begin with the calculation of the correct "monthweek" number :

```
wk <- function(x) as.numeric(format(x, "%U")); 
daily_xts$mw <- wk(index(daily_xts)) - wk(as.Date(cut(index(daily_xts),"month"))) +1
```

Keep in mind that one month can be spread out over 6 calendar weeks, so we can have "monthweek" numbers 1- 6. November 2014 would be an example.

To get the mean by month by "monthweek" i. e. for the 'jobs':

```
daily_xts$mo <- strftime(index(daily_xts), "%m")
daily_xts$yr <- strftime(index(daily_xts), "%Y")
monthweek <- aggregate( jobs ~ mw + mo + yr , daily_xts, FUN = mean)
```

The last 2 lines are for 'cosmetics' and add a date column and remove the now 'unnecessary' 'mo' and 'yr' columns from the resulting data frame.

```
monthweek$date <- as.POSIXct(paste(monthweek$yr, monthweek$mo, "01", sep = "-")) 
monthweek <- monthweek[,c(5,4)]
```

If you don't want to go with the "correct" week numbers you can always aggregate for instance week 4 and 5 into one group. I leave that as an exercise :-)